# Render, viewport "Rendered" preview, and material preview white

Tags: rendering

I've been working on a scene for a while now with no issues. Today, I found that when I rendered the scene, it came out as completely white. Furthermore, the material preview window is also showing completely white.

I've noticed that, until a few samples have been calculated, you can actually see some of the scene/material in the previews, but after just a few samples, the scene goes completely white. Here's a screenshot I managed to take of this phenomenon.

[image: Sample screenshot 1]

And a screenshot of the material preview, which behaves similarly.

[image: Sample screenshot 2]

I've checked everything I know to check (which honestly isn't very much) and can't seem to figure out what's up. I've uploaded a copy of my scene (with most of the models removed) to demonstrate the problem here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4535/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being the curves I had set for the Filmic OpenColorIO configuration:

[image: Screenshot of curves]

Somewhere along the way I accidentally reset the White Level values to zero.

Comment: Instead of using curves in the color management settings, try using a CDL mode as part of your node tree.

Comment: @cegaton Happy to give it a shot, but I don't understand (1) why the issue manifested in the first place, and (2) why resetting the curves and then recreating them fixed the issue.

Comment: The issue is that with those curves you have not set the correct values for the **white level**. In the image you have set them at 0, for your curve to work they should be at least 1

Comment: @cegaton Good observation, I didn't even notice. I must have zeroed them out somehow accidentally. Mystery solved!

Comment: It is best if you avoid using the curves in the color management section.

Answer (score 4):

Your scene is simply too bright. If you lower the exposure to -10 in the Scene panel, you can start to see the color of the surfaces.

A more permanant fix is to lower the energy intensity of your 2 lamps in the scene, as well as the world HDR map.

Comment: Hm, changing the exposure does seem to help some, but adjusting the lamps or the HDR doesn't affect the material preview, and -10 is the minimum exposure value. I know all those values were the same in this scene before; I must have changed something else I suppose?

Comment: Try using the false color look in the color management settings to set the proper values when using filmoc blender.